# TypeScript: Modify class before type checking

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api, typescript-decorator

I would like to implement a library similar to https://projectlombok.org/ in Java. For example, let's assume I'd like to implement a simple `@Setter` decorator that would add `setXyz()` methods for each field `xyz` in the class.

Is this possible? e.g. compile-time decorators or a "plugin" to the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

With TypeScript decorators you can only change runtime behaviour. The objective is that you do not change the runtime *usage* (aka the compile time interface) of the input.

## More

- Docs http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html
- Real world example `@observable` : https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx

Enjoy

Comment: I believe this works at run-time. What I want is to do this during compilation phase: in my example, I'd like to be able to call <code>obj.setXYZ(42)</code> and do not get a compilation error

Comment: Sorry you can't. Updated answer 

Answer (score 0):

The Typescript compiler does not currently support "plugins". In fact [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16607) is an open Typescript issue on GitHub for adding such behavior.

That said, one option you have for doing this would be to also run your project through a bundler such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), which definitely supports plugins and transforms. There are plenty of resources for getting started with webpack plugin development, but you could try starting [here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/how-to-write-a-plugin).